# Equivalent ADB command in Termux

Tags: adb, 7.1-nougat, termux

Is there any command equivalent to `adb cmd package compile -m everything -f` in termux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works. You just need root to do this:

```
$ tsu -a
# cmd package compile -m everything -f
```

Or:

```
$ tsu -c '/system/bin/cmd package compile -m everything -f'
```

Comment: @IrfanLatif Good to know that. Thanks. I didn't realize that I edited my files to automatically do that.

Comment: Though I get CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/cmd": cannot locate symbol "XzUnpacker_Construct" referenced by "/system/lib/libunwind.so"...
, but it seems that it will work if I fix it. Thanks!